# Como converter encriptação de Python para PHP?

Tags: php, python, login, hash

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível a conversão dessa encryptação para a linguagem de PHP, eu preciso converter as senhas que foram geradas para serem aceitas no meu sistema de Login no site, mas eu não sei como fazer.

**Eu tenho um banco de dados com senhas geradas com essa encryptação no Python:**

***Código Python:***

```
password = "senha do usuario na DB"    
base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(password).hexdigest() + "\xf7\x1a\xa6\xde\x8f\x17v\xa8\x03\x9d2\xb8\xa1V\xb2\xa9>\xddC\x9d\xc5\xdd\xceV\xd3\xb7\xa4\x05J\r\x08\xb0").digest())
```

***Código de Login no PHP:***

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['iniciar'])) {
    $usuario = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['senha'];

    $sql = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$usuario'");

    while ($login = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $usuarioDB = $login['Username'];
        $passwordDB = $login['Password2'];
    }
    if ($usuario == isset($usuarioDB) && password_verify($password, $passwordDB)) {
        $_SESSION['logged'] = "Logged";
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuarioDB;
        $_SESSION['senha'] = $passwordDB;
        header("Location: index.php");
    } elseif ($usuario !== isset($usuarioDB)) {
        echo "<div class='error'><span>Login inválido.</span></div>";
    } elseif (password_verify($password, $passwordDB) === FALSE) {
        echo "<div class='error'><span>Senha inválida.</span></div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Agradeço por qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é \x nas strings de Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228024)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Entendo que o trecho do seu código Python `"\xf7\x1a\xa6\xde\x8f\x17v\xa8\x03\x9d2\xb8\xa1V\xb2\xa9>\xddC\x9d\xc5\xdd\xceV\xd3\xb7\xa4\x05J\r\x08\xb0"` seja um salt.

Sendo assim, primeiramente, o mesmo deve ser armazenado no PHP.

```
$salt = "\xf7\x1a\xa6\xde\x8f\x17v\xa8\x03\x9d2\xb8\xa1V\xb2\xa9>\xddC\x9d\xc5\xdd\xceV\xd3\xb7\xa4\x05J\r\x08\xb0";
```

O segundo detalhe é que a função `password_verify` usa internamente uma criptografia gerada pela função `crypt` internamente. Porém, como no Python você está usando o hash `sha256`, creio que a abordagem correta seria usar a função `hash` do PHP com o primeiro argumento sendo `sha256`.

Também notei que em Python é usado o `base64` para gerar o hash. Nesse caso você precisará da função no PHP que fará algo semelhante, que é `base64_encode`.

Veja:

```
$hash = hash('sha256', hash('sha256', $password) . $salt));

base64_encode($hash) === $login['Password2']
```

Nota: Talvez por questão de interpretação seu salt (que parece estar em hexadecimal) deverá ser armazenando numa variável usando aspas duplas, já que o `\x` é interpretado de maneira diferente pelo PHP em tais casos.

Comment: Refiz dessa forma e deu certo!
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Por que o -1? Não entendi

Comment: Era pra eu clicar em +1, cliquei por engano em -1 eu acho, e agora não consigo reverter...

Comment: @DevDansh consegue sim. É só clicar no +1 :p

Comment: Eu cliquei, aparece a seguinte mensagem:
"Obrigado pelo feedback! Votos de usuários com menos de 15 de reputação reputação são registrados, mas não mudam a pontuação mostrada no post."

Comment: @DevDansh não foi você que votou negativo, amigo. Fica tranquilo. Que bom que a resposta ajudou :p

Comment: Que susto!
Haha, valeu mano!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63676/discussion-between-devdansh-and-wallace-maxters).

Comment: O código em Python chama a função sha256 duas vezes.. A resposta proposta deveria refletir isso.
Ademais, o conteúdo de uma string com prefixos \xHH em Python é bem claro - deve existir alguma forma correta de se criar uma string similar em PHP sem precisar de 'acho que isso é equivalente' - nem que seja uma função que tenha um loop que aplique várias vezes chr(hexdec(caracteres)) e concatene os resultados.

Comment: @jsbueno você tem razão. O `sha256` realmente é chamado duas vezes, mas agora estou surpreso do AR ter dito que funcionou, sendo que também eu errei quando coloquei `+` ao invés de colocar o operador de concatenação que é o `.`.