# O que é "\x" nas strings em Python?

Tags: python, string

Respondi [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227999/como-converter-encripta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-python-para-php) aqui no site onde existia a seguinte string na linguagem Python:

```
"\xf7\x1a\xa6\xde\x8f\x17v\xa8\x03\x9d2\xb8\xa1V\xb2\xa9>\xddC\x9d\xc5\xdd\xceV\xd3\xb7\xa4\x05J\r\x08\xb0"
```

Imagino que esse `\x` tenha alguma relação com algum tipo de codificação, mas não tenho certeza do que se trata.

O que seria esse `\x` na string? Tem a ver com hexadecimal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É uma sequencia de escape, significa que os dois caracteres seguintes devem ser interpretados como digitos hexa-decimais para interpretação de codigo de caracters:

Experimente no terminal:

```
>>> 0x65
101

>>> "\x65"
'e'
```

`0xHH` É utilizado literalmente, isto é, o número hexa literal, se usado como string (`"\xHH"`) é utilizado para representação de caracter.

Answer (score 2):

O `"\xHH" dentro de uma string indica que os próximos dois caractéres (inidcaodos por "H") seraão interpretados como dígitos hexadecimais, e portanto, é uma forma de se representar qualquer byte arbitrário dentro de uma string em Python.

Assim, `b"\xff"` vai corresponder a uma byte string com um único byte de valor 255 (ff em hexadecimal).

É importante ter em mente que em Python 3, assim como nas strings unicode  de Python 2, um byte desses não necessariamente corresponderia a um caractere. Por conta da codificação específica utilizada para texto em Python 3, todos os bytes de 0 a 255 correspondem a codificação de caractéres conhecida como "latin1" - a mesma usada em muitas versões do Windows para o Português Brasileiro.  Isso significa que qualquer byte arbitrário especificado com o prefixo `"\xHH"` vai corresponder a um caractere imprimível de texto em Python 3.

Uma experiência interessante pode ser gravar dados numéricos num arquivo binário, le-los como texto e ver como aparece a representação:

```
In [23]: f = open("teste.bin", "wb")

In [24]: f.write(bytearray((0, 0, 255, 255, 128, 128)))
Out[24]: 6

In [25]: f.close()

In [26]: open("teste.bin", encoding="latin1").read()
Out[26]: '\x00\x00ÿÿ\x80\x80'
```

(No caso, o caractére Ÿ tem o código 255 (0xff): )
In [30]: print("\xff")
ÿ

De forma similar, em Python 3 (e em strings Unicode de Python2), o prefixo `\u` permite designar um caractére unicode direto pelo seu valor de codepoint - para codepoints de até 16 bits (quatro dígitos hexadecimais)

Assim, por exemplo, o caractere de codepoint 0x263A, que é o emoji de carinha sorridente, pode ser colocado diretamente em código fonte Python:

```
In [42]: a = "\u263a"

In [43]: print(a)
☺
```

E par caracteres mais "longínquos", o prefixo `\U` (com "U" maiúsculo) permite 8 dígitos hexadecimais - para expressar caracteres com codepoint maior que 65535 (0xffff). A semântica de "\xHH", "\uHHHH" e "\UHHHHHHHH" é a mesma.

Agora, o que pode ser interessante é que as vezes pegamos uma string "codificada duas vezes" - isso é, em que a sequência de `\xHH` tem de fato quatro caractéres (por exemplo, se salvarmos um arquivo .txt com a sequência `\x41` - de forma que seja um arquivo de 4 bytes). Se quisermos ler o único caractére representado pelo byte 0x41 ("A" maiúsculo), temos que fazer algumas manobras. Para simplificar podemos simplesmente escapar a própria "\" escrevendo "\" num string de Python (sempre Python 3):

```
In [37]: a
Out[37]: 'A'

In [38]: a = "\\x41"

In [39]: len(a)
Out[39]: 4

In [40]: a
Out[40]: '\\x41'
```

Ou seja - nesse caso, temos a "\" como um caractere separado - e não como um caractére que é combinado com o "x" e os dois dígitos seguintes em tempo de compilação pelo Python. Para podermos "compilar" isso para um único bytem temos que "descodificar" (decode) esse texto usando o codec especial "unicode_escape".  Só que , não é tao simples - você não pode aplicar "decode" em um texto em Python 3, por que ele já é considerado "decoded" - você precisa ter uma byte-string para poder chamar o método decode. Como nossa variável "a" é uma string, a solução é converte-la primeiro para bytes, usando o método "encode" - usamos a codificação "latin1" que conveninentemente não altera nenhum valor do conteúdo, desde que seja um caractere com código menor que 255:

```
In [41]: a.encode("latin1").decode("unicode_escape")
Out[41]: 'A'
```